# Crear formulario en google sheets con buscador select

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Actualmente he creado un formulario que permita buscar información que se tiene en una hoja de cálculo que se encuentra en Google Sheets. Sólo lleno un campo en el primer `input` y doy click en el campo azul y se autocompleta los campos de país y color d polo.
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyIG0yETD73_6I1o3Yi8vBYuR2hVmLZSrcoqvZSiPs1X8zksBiR/exec , este es su código

**index.html**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<script>

   function buscaInformacion(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getLlegada). getLlegadaSS(document.forms[0]);
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getSalida). getSalidaSS(document.forms[0]);
   }

   function getLlegada(llegada){
     var txtLlegada = document.getElementById('llegada');
     txtLlegada.value = llegada;
   }

   function getSalida(salida){
      var txtSalida = document.getElementById('salida');
      txtSalida.value = salida;
   }

   $(function() {
      $( "#buscar" ).click(buscaInformacion);
   });

  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
     var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
       });
       }
     }

   window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

   function mostrar_mensaje() {
     var valor=document.getElementById("id").value;
     if(valor!=""){
        $("#suggesstion-box").show();
     }else{
       $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
     }
   }

  function selectCountry(val,val2,val3) {
    $("#id").val(val);
    $("#llegada").val(val2);
    $("#salida").val(val3);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
   }
  </script>

  <html>
  <body bgcolor="e3e5e8">
  <br><br>

  <div align="center" >

  <form id="datosPersona" name="datosPersona" autocomplete="off">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <label for="llegada">NOMBRE</label>
        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" onkeyup="mostrar_mensaje();">
         <div id="suggesstion-box" style="position: absolute;display: none">
         <ul id="country-list" style="background-color: #aac5f5;width: 300px" >
          <li onClick="selectCountry('valor 1','completar 1.1','completar 1.2');">valor 1</li>
         <li onClick="selectCountry('valor 2','completar 2.1','completar 2.2');">valor 2</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <label for="llegada">PAIS</label>
    <input type="text" id="llegada" name="llegada">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <label for="salida">COLOR POLO</label>
      <input type="text" id="salida" name="salida" >
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

  <br><br><br>
   <button id="buscar">Buscar</button>

   </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Cuando pongo un valor en el campo de `id="id"` , me muestra un `div`, el cual tiene `<ul></ul>`, y la información que se tiene dentro del `<li>` es que lo que yo doy por predeterminado, pero lo que busco es que me aparezca información que se tiene en una hoja de cálculo como BASE DE DATOS, y se autocomplete de acuerdo al `<li>` que de click.

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta es demasiado amplia, por otro lado el HTML no incluye ninguna etiqueta `select`. ¿Debemos entender que quieres reemplazar la etiqueta `input` con `id="id"` por  una etiqueta  `select`? ¿Que te ha impedido hacerlo en el código de la pregunta?

Comment: no quiero reemplazar el input con id="id" por un select, sino que debajo de ese input tener un div oculto, que aparezca cuando ingrese un valor. esa imagen que subi es eso, pero yo lo hize con html,php,javascript,mysql ... pero en este caso quiero hacerlo en formulario de google

Comment: Agrega eso a la pregunta y edita el título.

Comment: @Rubén ya lo agregue

Comment: Me refería a agregar tu comentario previo, pero bueno, agregar el código que usa PHP no está mal pero deberías revisar la redacción pues no se entiende que tiene que ver ese código con lo que estás preguntando. Considera que la pregunta debe ser clara sin necesidad de leer los comentarios o contenido externo.

Comment: sabes como solucionarlo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97941/discussion-between-ruben-and-kevincs7).

Answer (score -1):

Para tomar datos de una hoja de cálculo de Google desde el código del lado del cliente se debe llamar una función del lado del servidor usando `google.script.run` como ya se hace en tu código.

En tu código del lado del cliente deberás agregar una función que haga la llamada al código del lado del cliente y que use el resultado para actualizar los elementos `<li>` del `<ul>`. Como lo mencionaste en un comentario, puedes usar un evento `onkeyup` o similiar, para lo cual es recomendable usar `addEventListener` al cargar la página.

Usando "Vanilla JavaScript" (sin librerías como jQuery), para reemplazar todos los elementos hijo del `ul` podrías usar

```
document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = resultado;
```

donde `resultado` es el lo que te devolvió la función del lado del servidor formada apropiadamente.

Cabe hacer notar que las llamadas a servicios de Google Apps Script como `SpreadsheetApp` son relativamente lentas y tienen cuotas relativamente pequeñas (comparándolo con un servicio de paga basado en hits, MB, uso de procesadores, etc) por lo que dependiendo del uso que le vayas a dar a tu aplicación es probable que debas buscar otra estrategia, quizás pasar los datos de tu hoja de cálculo a una plataforma como Firebase y que el código del lado del cliente lo tome de dicha plataforma.

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quotas